# Argument labels '(rawValue:)' do not match any available overloads (xcode error)

Tags: swift, xcode, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have a flutter code and I compile it swift and every thing is working except one error

> (Argument labels '(rawValue:)' do not match any available overloads
>   (xcode error))

Code:

```
func close() {
    dismiss(animated: true)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400), execute: {() -> Void in
        self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0.0)
        UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.makeKeyAndVisible()

        if (self.statusDelegate != nil) {
            self.statusDelegate?.safariExit(uuid: self.uuid)
        }
    })
}
```

please help

Comment: Most probably, it is a programming error, and not an Xcode error :)

Comment: There is some mismatch between expected formatting and what you have written. For which line you are getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising the `UIWindow.Level` with the wrong type.  You are using a a literal value of 0.0 which will be inferred to be a `Double` when the method signature is: `init(rawValue: CGFloat)`.  You need to either use a CGFloat variable or cast the literal to a CGFloat

```
self.tmpWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: CGFloat(0.0))
```

Comment: That is not correct: `UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0.0)` *does* compile (because CGFloat conforms to ExpressibleByFloatLiteral).

Comment: Doh!   Should have picked that up - thanks for the correction!